# Exchange 2016 server How I can reocgnize if the client configured like POP3 or MAPI client?

Tags: exchange-server

Does Somebody know how I can see on the Exchange server 2016 if my client is configured like POP3 or MAPI client?
Somewhere in the Logs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Outlook with Exchange 2016 somewhat 'standard' installation then MAPI over HTTP/S will be automatically enabled and your Outlook clients will be using it to connect. Then you can use the IIS logs to view the connections (these will be MAPI only).

If you are using a POP3/IMAP clients and the services are enabled on Exchange then I think you need to enable protocol logging via `Set-PopSettings` and `Set-ImapSettings` respectively and then review the protocol logs to see the connections. Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/configure-protocol-logging-for-pop3-and-imap4-exchange-2013-help) for more info on these logs.